# How could we know that the universe is homogeneous and isotropic at a moment?

Tags: cosmology

Cosmologists say that the universe is homogeneous and isotropic within our Hubble volume  based upon the astronomical observations. But how can we argue that the universe is homogeneous and isotropic at any particular moment while we can't picture the entire universe simultaneously due to the finite speed of light? i.e. when we picture the universe we picture the past. The further we go the further in time we observe.

Comment: Are you talking here of a space or time related isotropy?

Comment: The universe is "spatially" homogeneous and isotropic. So actually I mean space.

Answer (score 4):

I think there are two ways to approach the question.

If you are coming from the point of view of a theoretician trying to come up with a working model of the universe, you would definitely like to make the assumption of isotropy and homogeneity. This is usually what we do, as least to first order approximation. One of the reasons for that is that the symmetry allows us to write useful and relatively simple solutions to Einstein's equations, like the FRW metric. Motivated by the fact that the universe is definitely not homogeneous at very small scales (read, scale of several galaxies), Cosmologists then add perturbations to this homogeneous and isotropic background, and see what they can get.

The second, more pragmatic approach is to look at the stars and see if the universe *is* homogeneous and isotropic. In other words, are the assumptions I discussed above justified. It turns out that they are. You were asking more specifically about the Hubble Radius, but it is not very much different from the observable universe. To sum up, we don't know for sure that the universe doesn't have a big "lump" just out of reach of what we can see today, but given what we *can* see and the fact that we have extremely accurate and predictive models of the universe that crucially rely on the basic assumptions of isotropy and homogeneity, it's a very justifiable thing to say.

Comment: exhaustives measures taken by wmap and planck agree with both principles

Comment: I want to speak pragmatically. Actually the universe is observed to be homogeneous and isotropic on large scales but here comes my question, we actually look at the past!

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is here. Do you mean that what we observe is the "past", therefore how do we know that the universe is homogeneous and isotropic in the "present"? Something along those lines?

Comment: Yeah exactly, I'm confused!

Comment: Ok I understand. First of all, the notion that things live "in the past" is wrong according to general relativity, but let us not comment on that here. The problem lies with the definition Homogeneous .  

Imagine that we are at the center of a sphere of radius r. The radius parametrises "how far back into the past" you are looking: bigger r means you are looking at things from a long time ago. By homogeneous, we mean that comparing different points on the same sphere of radius r, we see much the same. This is true for most r, but you have to compare points at the same r.

Comment: @pploops: wouldn't you say "you have to compare points at the same $r$ and at the same $t$"? Isn't this the core of our biased point of observation?

Comment: @daniel Azuelos: In this picture, $t$ _is_ $r$. Indeed, information that you see on  earth is carried by photons travelling at $c$. So information that you get today from something distance $ r $ away happened  at a time of $t = r/c$ in the past (I am being loose with units).

Comment: Hence for $r>>1$ we have a version of universe properties which are very old. If we compare the density of galaxies and find they are the same *from our point of vue, now and there*, this can't be used to deduce any global isotropy over $r$ and $t$.---- To make an uttermost hypothesis, it is completly possible that what we receive as an image of the universe doesn't exist anymore. All these galaxies might have disappeared billion years ago.

Comment: @daniel Azuelos: You correctly understood that  what we're comparing is the density of matter distribution from _our point of view_. But that's just the thing, our point of view is the only thing that makes physical sense to talk about. The notion that what we see doesn't exist any more is wrong: If you were to travel to these places at the speed of light, starting today, you would literally be _travelling to the future_. In other words, the best notion of "now" that we have for galaxies that we observe billions of light year away, is only what we see today.

Comment: @daniel Azuelos: I think part of the confusion stems from some of the examples used to describe the notion of space-time in special relativity. For example, there is this idea that if the sun were to suddenly drop out of existence, we would not know about it until a few minutes later. This statement is totally wrong. The event of the sun's disappearance will happen for us earth mongers, exactly when we see the sun disappear. If you had a friend hanging out next to the sun, and he decided to tell you when he sees it happen, _there is nothing he can do to alert you of the disappearance earlier_.

Comment: Then, since the time anisotropy of the universe seems like the most accepted model, how would a space isotropy model withstand? ---- But perhaps should this be a completly different question (story :) )?

Comment: Yes, at this stage we're getting quite off-topic :). I would recommend asking a separate question, or reading about special relativity.